# 'Algebraic' way to prove the boolean identity $a + \overline{a}*b = a + b$

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

For me, it is pretty clear that $a + \overline{a}*b = a + b$, because the first $a$ in the `or` will make sure that if the second term must be 'evaluated', $a$ will always be false, and therefore won't matter in the `and` - probably because I'm a programmer and it is very common to see this unnecessary cluttering in long `if-else` structures.

I can easily prove it with the truth table as well, just make both expressions', and turns out they are identical.

But I was looking for a 'algebraic' way to prove it. That is, something using the basic operations properties like the fact that they are `transitive`, `commutative`, `associative`, etc. For example, if I was to prove this other simple identity $a + a*b = a$ I would simply do something like:

$a + a*b = a*(1 + b) = a*1 = a$.

Is there a way to also prove the former using this algebraic operations, without resorting to the truth table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$a + \bar a*b \overset{(1)}{=} (a+\bar a) * (a + b) \overset{(2)}{=} 1 *(a + b) = a+b$$

We simply use $(1)$ distribution of $a$ over the product $\bar a *b$, and $(2)$ the identity that $a + \bar a = 1$.

Comment: I didn't know $a + bc = (a + b)(a + c)$ is true in boolean algebra... That will do the trick as well!

Comment: @LuanNico That's the pity about the $\;+\;$ and $\;*\:$ notation, and giving them different precedence: it hides the fact that these boolean operators are each other's duals, especially if $\;*\;$ is left out: $\;a+bc=(a+b)(a+c)\;$ and $\;a(b+c)=ab+ac\;$ look very different from each other, but writing $\;a \lor (b \land c) = (a \lor b) \land (a \lor c)\;$ and $\;a \land (b \lor c) = (a \land b) \lor (a \land c)\;$ makes the duality clear.

Answer (score 2):

You can always resort to a normal form that is effectively equivalent to the truth table:

$$ a + (\bar{a} \cdot b) = (a \cdot (b + \bar{b})) + (\bar{a} \cdot b) 
= (a \cdot b) + (a \cdot \bar{b}) + (\bar{a} \cdot b) $$

and similarly for $a+b$.

---

Your own reasoning by splitting into what happens in the case of $a$ and in the case of $\bar{a}$ can be applied too:

$$ \begin{align}a+b &= (a + \bar{a}) \cdot (a+b)
\\&= (a \cdot (a+b)) + (\bar{a} \cdot (a+b))
\\&= ((a \cdot a) + (a \cdot b)) + ((\bar{a} \cdot a) + (\bar{a} \cdot b))
\\&= \cdots \end{align}$$

(the argument could be streamlined, but I'm intentionally making it in a very formulaic way)

Comment: Thanks! Both very elegant ways to do it.